# This import contains errors, which may affect components that depend on this NgModule

Tags: angular, angular-material

**CAUSE**: Inject data variable in a component in Angular:
*ex.:*

```
constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {}
```

**EFFECT**:

```
Error: src/app/app.module.ts:24:5 - error NG6002: This import contains errors, which may affect components that depend on this NgModule.

24     HomeModule,
       ~~~~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/layout/home/home.module.ts:30:9 - error NG6002: This import contains errors, which may affect components that depend on this NgModule.

30         DialogModule
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I have tried to reinstall node_modules and analyzed the code

Answer (score 6):

**Solution**: Restart the web server

1. ctrl+c
2. ng serve

Comment: You just saved me from going down the rabbit hole.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the MS's answer: clearing the cache and running ng serve again after was the solution for me.

Steps:

1. stop ng serve (ctrl+c)
2. npm cache clean --force
3. ng serve